# Making CSS clip rect responsive

Tags: jquery, css, clipping, clip

I'm trying to implement a little something here: http://atmapp.io/beta/

I'm clipping a Google Maps object, to fit in the phone area. It works great on 1920x1080 (mainly because I hardcoded the rect's values). How can I make the `clip: rect` responsive?

I've tried with jQuery, but I'm an idiot, and I'm probably miles off:

**CSS**

```
#map-canvas2 {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  bottom: 0;
  clip:rect(191px, 1579px, 732px, 1275px);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var oldresX = 1920;
var oldresY = 943;
var rectTop = 191;
var rectRight = 1579;
var rectBottom = 732;
var rectLeft = 1275;
var newRectTop;
var newRectRight;
var newRectBottom;
var newRectLeft;

var newResX;
var newResY;


$(window).resize(function(){
    newResY = oldresY - window.innerHeight;
    newResX = oldresX - window.innerWidth;

    newRectTop = rectTop + newResY;
    newRectRight = rectRight - newResX;
    newRectBottom = rectBottom - newResY;
    newRectLeft = rectLeft + newResX;

    //alert(newResX + "x" + newResY);
    $("#map-canvas2").css('clip', 'rect('+newRectTop +'px, '+newRectRight +'px, '+newRectBottom +'px, '+ newRectLeft+'px)');
    //alert('rect('+newRectTop +'px, '+newRectRight +'px, '+newRectBottom +'px, '+ newRectLeft+'px)');
});
```

**EDIT**

For those wondering, this is how the map is supposed to "fit":
[image]

Comment: So what is the problem? The page works fine on my iPhone

Comment: For clip to work with a responsive layout then you would need to use percentage values. Percentage values are not supported for clip though. You could try to use clip-path instead. Check out http://species-in-pieces.com/#

Comment: @idmean, the second map doesn't show up on mobile.

Comment: @jackson, thanks for the tip. I did `   <svg height="100%" width="100%">
       <defs>
           <clipPath id="svgPath">
        <rect x="67%" y="19%" width="16%" height="60%" />
           </clipPath>
       </defs>
   </svg>
` , but to no avail. I've updated the page, so you can see it in action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clip-path` with `inset` basic shape instead of deprecated `clip`.
Don't forget about `-webkit` prefix.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: -1px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

section {
  margin: 1em;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
  
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50% 0 4px 1em);
  clip-path: inset(50% 0 4px 1em);
}
```

```html
<section><div></div></section>
```